# C#: HTTP Post with Authentication issue

Tags: c#, json, http, post, get

I'm trying to learn how to work with a REST API. Unfortunately the one i'm using requires authentication and I can't get my code right. Anyone willing to help me get my code straight?

```
 using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace HttpClientAuth
    {
        class Program
        {
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                var userName = "admin";
                var passwd = "adminpw";
                var url = "http://10.10.102.109/api/v1/routing/windows/Window1";

                using var client = new HttpClient();

                var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{passwd}");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));

                var result = await client.GetAsync(url);

                var requestContent = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

                //Request Body in Key Value Pair
                requestContent.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["CanYCentre"] = "540",
                    ["CanXCentre"] = "960",
                });

                var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey try `Update 2` just copy and paste. on your code base ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are confused how you could make a `POST` request. You could try below snippet.

```
         ApiRequestModel _requestModel = new ApiRequestModel();

        _requestModel.RequestParam1 = "YourValue";
        _requestModel.RequestParam2= "YourValue";


        var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_requestModel);
        var authKey = "c4b3d4a2-ba24-46f5-9ad7-ccb4e7980da6";
        var requestURI = "http://10.10.102.109/api/v1/routing/windows/Window1";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(requestURI);
            request.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + authKey);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);


            //Check status code and retrive response

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                dynamic objResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                dynamic result_string = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

        }
```

**Update:** As per your given screenshot on comment you could also try this way.

```
private async Task<string> HttpRequest()
    {
        //Your Request End Point
        string requestUrl = $"http://10.10.102.109/api/v1/routing/windows/Window1";
        var requestContent = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);

        //Request Body in Key Value Pair
        requestContent.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["CanYCentre"] = "540",
            ["CanXCentre"] = "960",
        });

        requestContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + "YourAuthKey");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //Sending request to endpoint
        var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(requestContent);
        //Receiving Response
        dynamic json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

        return response;
    }
```

***Update 2:***

```
If you still don't understand or don't know how you would implement it Just copy and paste below code snippet.


  private static async Task<string> HttpRequest()
        {

            object[] body = new object[] 
            {
                new { CanYCentre = "540" },
                new { CanYCentre = "960" }
            };
            var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://10.10.102.109/api/v1/routing/windows/Window1");
                request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + "YourAuthKey");

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseBody);
                return result;
            }

        }
```

Hope this would help you. If you encounter any problem feel free to share.

Comment: You could try with your local host request would send, are you sure your request is alright as per your server requirement ?

Comment: Yeah I've seen , Updated the answer if its work for you. Let  me know your update.

Comment: ha ha that's silly man make your method `static` because your main method is `static` and remember `non static` field cannot be instantiated inside `static field` just try `private static async Task<string> HttpRequest()`

Comment: Like this format is universal   `requestContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + "YourAuthKey");`

Comment: Ok like above? I still need to deal with the NotImplememntedExeption. Any hint on that?

Comment: Just copy my code , delete all of your code outside `main method` , and paste my code there, finally call it inside `main method`

Comment: I did a full overhaul of my code, this one is working an giving me status code 200! It looks like my BODY isn't working yet so will do some testing

Comment: Done thank you! It had to be a PUT by the way and not a POST. Still my body seems not to work well but will open a different topic on the body question.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for an alternative version of a C# Http JSON PUT with Authentication:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //URL
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://url");

            //Basic Authentication
            string authInfo = "admin" + ":" + "adminpw";
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

            //Application Type
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            //Method
            httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

            // JSON Body
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"ID\":\"1\"," +
                              "\"Phone\":\"1234567890\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                Console.WriteLine("PUT Body: " + json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Status Code
            Console.WriteLine("URL: " + httpWebRequest.RequestUri);
            Console.WriteLine("Status Discription " + httpResponse.StatusDescription);

            if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status code " +(int)httpResponse.StatusCode + " " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status code " + (int)httpResponse.StatusCode + " " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
            }
            // Close the response.
            httpResponse.Close();
        }
    }
}
```